# InvalidOperation Exception in PhotoCaptureDevice

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

When i call the method PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(...) in Windows Phone 8 it throws the following exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object.    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at JPMC.Controls.CaptureTaskLauncher.d_*6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b*_0(Object
>   state)}

What might be the problem ? Anyone can you help me ?

Comment: If running on a simulator using your webcam (I'm not sure how you try) try in release mode by with Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the exception message *"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"* I'm guessing you already have an PhotoCaptureDevice initialized? And it's open? So you'll need to close the open PhotoCaptureDevice by calling Dispose() or cache a it in a field for later use.